# Cannot get a BSTR in VB6 dll from a referenced C++ dll

Tags: c++, dll, vb6

Let me start off by saying that VB is not my strong suit.

I am developing a C++ dll to be used in a VB6 application's dll.

I have successfully instantiated the (C++) classes in VB. I am trying to access data members of the class using this syntax: "`vbCppObj.dataMemberName`".

I can confirm that this works for boolean and enum types and it invokes the getter methods defined in my class.

I have to access a string from the (C++) class as well. 
The getter function for the string is given below:

```
class MyCPPClass
{
private:
WCHAR* CPPErrorString = L"This is a string";

public:
HRESULT __stdcall get_CPPErrorString(BSTR* pVal)
{
BSTR str = ::SysAllocString(CPPErrorString);
if(str)
*pVal = str;
return S_OK;
}
};
```

I am unable to debug the C++ dll right now.

I access this value in the VB6 code as follows:

```
ErrorString = vbCppObj.CPPErrorString
Logger.log "[Log]:" & ErrorString
```

"`ErrorString`" is a String type in VB. When this line executes, the "`ErrorString`" object shows "`<Out of memory>`" (when I hover over it). If I step further, to the logging code, it gives me a "Error 14: Out of string space".

Also, I have typed this code in the browser so, it may not be 100% correct.

Comment: Correction:
The "ErrorString" object shows "Out of Memory" (when I hover over it)

Comment: Let me start by saying: C++ is not mine *g*. But maybe you will find the microsoft support pages useful: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205277   and    http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/106553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had to convert the string into a "_b_str" and then to a "BSTR". That worked for me.

I had tried it earlier but I don't know why it didn't work at that time.

Answer (score -1):

Why you just don't use LPCTSTR?
I'm not an advanced C/C++ programmer, but this should work

```
class MyCPPClass
{
    private:
        LPCTSTR CPPErrorString = "This is a string";

    public:
        HRESULT __stdcall get_CPPErrorString(LPCTSTR * pVal)
        {
            // copy the value
            *pVal = CPPErrorString;

            // return
            return S_OK;
        }
}
```